# Laravel 5 - What is wrong with this filter?

Tags: regex, filter, laravel-5

I  want this Route

```
Route::get('/{var?}',['uses'=>'indexController@wrongCredentials', 'as'=>'wrongCred'])->where('var', '[wrongCredentials]+');
```

Send to the `indexController@wrongCredentials` only and just only the `URL:myproject.com/wrongCredentials`.

It is not working.

If I type `/rat, /wo, /wrongCredentials`, and others strings the code sends me to the controller.

If I type `/bat, cat/` and others don't.

I've already tried others combinations like:

```
Route::get('/{var?}',['uses'=>'indexController@wrongCredentials', 'as'=>'wrongCred'])->where('var', '[^wrongCredentials$]+');

Route::get('/{var?}',['uses'=>'indexController@wrongCredentials', 'as'=>'wrongCred'])->where('var', '[/^wrongCredentials$/]+');


Route::get('/{var?}',['uses'=>'indexController@wrongCredentials', 'as'=>'wrongCred'])->where('var', '/^[wrongCredentials]$/+');
```

But none of them worked properly.

Can someone tell what am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried `Route::get('/{var?}',['uses'=>'indexController@wrongCredentials', 'as'=>'wrongCred'])->where('var', 'wrongCredentials');`

Comment: wow, that worked ! I dont know I was so fixed to REGEX.

Comment: Ok, glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use "wrongCredentials" without special characters
`Route::get('/{var?}',['uses'=>'indexController@wrongCredentials', 'as'=>'wrongCred'])->where('var', 'wrongCredentials');`